# Looking for debugging advice for "lost" workers that received SIGTERM during processing

Tags: python, celery

Looking for debugging advice for "lost" workers that received SIGTERM during processing.

We use a distributed batch processing environment using a few hundred celery workers on Amazon EC2 instances within an auto scaling group and using RabbitMQ. We have bursts of usage throughout the day - usually not continuous. We scale up workers when messages get put on the queue. We scale down after 10 consecutive minutes of having no messages on the queue. Each job request can produce thousands of messages. We use a considerable number of compositions of chords (chords of chords).

We are currently experiencing an issue with our Celery workers after a migration of our processing system from Python 3.6 to 3.7 and from Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2 within our EC2 instances. There have been no other software-related changes. For example, we are using Celery 4.4.7 and RabbitMQ v3.8.2 in both the old and new environments.

Some of the workers are reporting a `WorkerLostError` with Signal 15 during processing and ultimately causes the processing job to fail. It appears that some external process is sending a SIGKILL message to the celery process on the worker. We've not been able to see anything in the logs that show what is sending that message and why. Note that the same processing job (same set of code) can be successful one time but not the next. Just seems to depend on where/when the celery worker is shut down. Also note that we have not had this issue prior to our environment migration (previously using Python 3.6 and Amazon Linux).

We've run some tests where we've adjusted the number of max workers in the ASG and it appears that the issue has a greater chance of occurring with the greater number of workers. For example, with just 50 workers we haven't seen the issue when running 20 test jobs. With 75 workers, we had 1 worker lost error with the 20 jobs. And with 250 workers, we had 10 failed jobs (of 20) due to the worker lost errors.
We've been able to rule out EC2-related issues such as memory, CPU, and disk space.

We are looking for suggestions as to how to further debug what is happening and understand the conditions that lead to lost worker errors and the overall celery process failing.

Included below is a stack trace of the Worker Lost Error and the pip list of software libraries.

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/opt/ev-backend/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/builtins.py", 
   line 83, in unlock_chord propagate=True, 
File "/opt/ev-backend/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", 
   line 781, in join disable_sync_subtasks=disable_sync_subtasks, 
File "/opt/ev-backend/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", 
   line 226, in get self.maybe_throw(callback=callback) File "/opt/ev-backend/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", 
   line 342, in maybe_throw self.throw(value, self._to_remote_traceback(tb)) 
File "/opt/ev-backend/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", 
   line 335, in throw self.on_ready.throw(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/opt/ev-backend/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", 
   line 244, in throw reraise(type(exc), exc, tb) 
File "/opt/ev-backend/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/five.py", 
   line 195, in reraise raise value celery.exceptions.ChordError: 
WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 15 Job: 0.')
```

Software libraries:

```
alembic 1.4.2 
amqp 2.6.1 
apsw 3.9.2.post1 
attrs 21.4.0 
aws-requests-auth 0.4.3 
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.7.0.1 
billiard 3.6.4.0 
blinker 1.4 
boto3 1.17.29 
botocore 1.20.112 
cachetools 4.2.1 
celery 4.4.7 
certifi 2021.10.8 
chardet 4.0.0 
ciso8601 2.1.3 
click 8.0.1 
coverage 6.3.1 
crontab 0.22.9 
Cython 0.29.22 
decorator 5.1.1 
dnspython 2.2.0 
elasticsearch 7.11.0 
email-validator 1.1.2 
Flask 1.1.2 
Flask-JsonSchema 0.1.1 
Flask-Mail 0.9.1 
Flask-Script 2.0.6 
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.4 
flask-talisman 0.7.0 
Flask-WTF 0.14.3 
frozendict 2.3.0 
future 0.18.2 
futures 3.1.1 
gitdb 4.0.9 
GitPython 3.1.2 
healthcheck 1.3.3 
idna 2.10 
importlib-metadata 4.10.1 
iniconfig 1.1.1 
itsdangerous 1.1.0 
Jinja2 3.0.3 
jmespath 0.10.0 
join 0.1.1 
jsonpath-rw 1.4.0 
jsonschema 3.2.0 
kombu 4.6.11 
Mako 1.1.6 
MarkupSafe 2.0.1 
numexpr 2.8.1 
numpy 1.19.5 
overrides 3.1.0 
packaging 21.3 
pandas 1.1.5 
passlib 1.7.4 
pip 21.2.4 
pluggy 1.0.0 
ply 3.11 
psutil 5.8.0 
psycopg2 2.8.6 
py 1.11.0 
pyasn1 0.4.8 
Pygments 2.8.1 
pyparsing 3.0.7 
pyrsistent 0.18.1 
pytest 7.0.0 
pytest-cov 2.11.1 
python-dateutil 2.8.1 
python-editor 1.0.4 
pytz 2020.1 
requests 2.25.1 
responses 0.13.1 
retrying 1.3.3 
rsa 4.7.2 
s3transfer 0.3.7 
scipy 1.5.4 
setuptools 60.8.2 
simplejson 3.17.2 
six 1.16.0 
smmap 5.0.0 
SQLAlchemy 1.3.23 
SQLAlchemy-Utils 0.36.5 
supervisor 4.1.0 
tables 3.6.1 
tomli 2.0.1 
typing_extensions 4.0.1 
urllib3 1.26.8 
vine 1.3.0 
Werkzeug 2.0.1 
wheel 0.37.1 
WTForms 2.3.3 
zipp 3.7.0
```

Comment: how does the ASG health-checks look like? don't you see that instances become unhealthy?

Comment: There are not custom health checks done.  We have been relying on the default healthchecks (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-health-checks.html)

Comment: I assumed that. I am asking you to make sure you checked the graph of unhealthy hosts to see correlation with your SINGTERM events. I assume that AWS send those and you need to tune the grace period before termination